# Algorithm - java, c# or delphi - search a number in array which exists more than arraySize / 2. In one pass without additional memory

Tags: c#, java, algorithm

I need to do an algorithm that search a specific int in array of int.
That number must appear >= than arraySize/2 times.

example: [] = 4 4 3 5 5 5 5 5 5 6
arraysize: 10
number 5 exists 6x -> so this is the result of algorithm

but I need to do this without additionam memory, and in time O(n) -> in one pass.

Is this even possible? Any suggestions how to start it?

Comment: Will you know which number to check for in advance, or do you need to check whether _any_ number occupies half or more of the array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linear time majority algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280450/linear-time-majority-algorithm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed possible; the task is known as "Dominant Element," and used for interviews and as a homework. Read the article below for a proper analysis; the solution itself is simple but not easy: proving that it indeed does what it promises is not quite trivial (unless of course you know the answer).

http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/sbaswana/Courses/ESO211/problem.pdf

> ```
> element x;
> int count ← 0;
> For(i = 0 to n − 1)
> {
>     if(count == 0) { x ← A[i]; count ++; }
>     else if (A[i] == x) count ++;
>     else count −−
> }
> Check if x is dominant element by scanning array A.
> ```

Note though that the time is O(n), but as far as I'm aware, it is *not* possible to do it in one pass *unless you know for sure there is a dominant element.*

As of additional memory, you will need memory for `i`, the counter; `x`, the element to check and return; and `count`, the size of the imaginary working set. That's O(1) and is usually considered OK for such problems.

Comment: Yep, the "trick" is in how the question is phrased.  For a positive answer there must be an element that is present more than 50% of the time.  Simply finding the most "popular" (but possibly not majority) element is an O(N**2) problem, unless additional storage is used.

Comment: Yep. **If** there is a majority element, that's the one you end up with, but if there isn't, `x` still has some value after the first loop, so you need to check. I disagree with 'proving ... far from being trivial', though. Given the algorithm, it's rather straightforward to prove its correctness. Coming up with the algorithm on the other hand ...

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm apparently not smart enough to prove its correctness—the idea of a working set modeled by an element and its count is not expressed in the code; without understanding this idea, it's not clear at all. Not to me, at least.

Comment: Work with an implicit second counter. Let `m` be the majority element, `n[i] = (number of occurrences of m in A[0] to A[i]) - (number of occurrences of other elements there)`. By induction, it's easy to see that `count[i] >= n[i]` for all `i` and `element == m` whenever `n[i] > 0`. Since `n[length-1] > 0` is assumed, it follows that the algorithm ends with the majority element if there is one.

Comment: @DanielFischer the *`element == m` whenever `n[i] > 0`* part evades me. How do we prove the induction step here? For `i`, `element == m` if `n[i] > 0`. For `i+1`, we don't know `n[i+1]`, and we don't know `n[i]`. The wording might be not right, though. Let me fix.

Comment: Induction hypothesis: the claim is true for all `i <= k`. Now we have to show it for `i == k+1`. So suppose `n[k+1] > 0`. Since `n[k+1] = n[k] + 1` if `A[k+1] == m` and `n[k+1] = n[k] - 1` otherwise, we know `n[k] >= 0`. If `n[k] > 0`, the induction hypothesis says at that point `element == m`, and since `count >= n[k] > 0`, `element` doesn't change at that step, so remains `m`. If on the other hand `n[k] == 0`, there are two possibilities, `count == 0` or `count > 0`. If `count == 0`, the algorithm sets `element = A[k+1]`, which is `m`, since `n[k+1] > n[k]`. ...

Comment: So it remains to see that if `count > 0 == n[k]`, then `element` can only be `m`. Suppose it were `e != m`. Introduce another counter, `ce[j]`, incremented whenever `A[j] != m` and decremented when `A[j] == m` (i.e., `ce[j] = -n[j]`). Whenever `e` is the selected element, `ce[j] >= count`. But `ce[k] == 0`, contradiction.  Hmm, the comments aren't the ideal place to coherently write it up, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Moore describes the solution to this problem on [his web site](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/mjrty/index.html) (with an example [here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/mjrty/example.html)).

Edit: Here is some Java code demonstrating the algorithm as described:

```
public class Majority 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[]a = new int[]{4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6};

        int count = 0;
        int candidateIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            if (count == 0)
            {
                candidateIndex = i;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (a[i] == a[candidateIndex])
                    count++;
                else
                    count--;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Majority element: " + a[candidateIndex]);
    }
}
```

After you get your `candidateIndex`, you can iterate though the array again to verify that it indeed occurs more than N / 2 times.

Comment: It does not work for 1,4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6,7,8,9,0,6,7,8